# Start application during Heroku CI

Tags: java, maven, heroku, continuous-integration, integration-testing

I want to implement integration/e2e tests during Heroku CI phase (which runs for each PR). Tests are connecting to a running server by REST API.

How can I do the DB migration and server startup during CI run (something similar to a review app)? I am using an [in-dyno postgres](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-ci-in-dyno-databases).

Comment: How far have you integrated with Heroku so far and why Heroku for CI tests?

Comment: I think I found the solution using environments>test>scripts>test-setup|test. Will post an answer after I make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried setting the following in `app.json`:

```
  "environments": {
    "test": {
      "addons": ["heroku-postgresql:in-dyno"],
      "scripts": {
        "test-setup": "mvn package -P no-tests && bash migrate.sh",
        "test": "bash server.sh && mvn test"
      }
    }
  }
```

This works, but the CI instance does not close, as the server is still running, timing out after 2 hours. Not cost efficient, so I ended up embedding the server instantiation in the integration tests, which is automatically closed once the tests finish.

Final `app.json`:

```
  "environments": {
    "test": {
      "addons": ["heroku-postgresql:in-dyno"],
      "scripts": {
        "test-setup": "mvn package -P no-tests && bash migrate.sh",
        "test": "mvn test"
      }
    }
  }
```